# Turn a class into a module in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class:

```
class Dice {
    div: Element;
    value: string;
    constructor(div: Element) {
        this.div = div;
    }
}
```

And I have `diceRoller` class extends the `Dice` Class:

```
class diceRoller extends Dice {
    static Values = Values;
    constructor(div: Element) {
        super(div);
        (this.div as HTMLElement).style.width = diceSize;
        (this.div as HTMLElement).style.height = diceSize;
        (this.div as HTMLElement).style.textAlign = 'center';
        (this.div as HTMLElement).style.lineHeight = diceSize;
        (this.div as HTMLElement).style.border = diceBorder;
        (this.div as HTMLElement).style.marginRight = '10px';
        (this.div as HTMLElement).style.cssFloat = 'left';
    }
    changeValue(val: number): boolean {
        this.value = Values[val];
        (this.div as HTMLElement).innerHTML = this.value;
        return true;
    }
}
```

How to turn the `diceRoller` class into a module. I've tried all the way in TypeScript handbook but I have not figured out yet.

Comment: Simply export it. `export class diceRoller ....` and `export class Dice ...`

Comment: I want to export the class with the form similar to export `{new diceRoller(div: Element)}` because I want to pass an argument to the class in the file that I import the module in. so, what is exactly the form?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to export the class with the form similar to export {new diceRoller(div: Element)} because I want to pass an argument to the class in the file that I import the module in. so, what is exactly the form

Simply:

```
export const foo = new diceRoller(div);
```

Comment: many thanks, I figured out for myself. I just add `export default` before the class `diceRoller`

Comment: I have tried to use your solution,but TypeScript flag an error on the argument `div`: `Can not find name 'div'`